# Express: Define views folder from remote machine

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, express, socket.io

How do i define the views folder that is presented in another shared machine? I can access the remote file in windows explorer by `\\0.0.0.0\myfolder` etc, but i cannot set the views folder to a place that is presented in another remote machine.

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));
app.engine('php', phpExpress.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'php');
```

This defines the views folder in my local machine. How will i set it if I want nodejs to look into a remote shared machine

Comment: What you need is define "views folder" from remote machine, right? If this is true, you can mount the remote folder to local (such as `/mnt/web_views`) and use the mount path: `app.set('views', path.join('/mnt/web_views'));`

Comment: The machine i am using is a shared windows machine so inside i passed it like this `app.set('views',path.join('//0.0.0.0/myProject/views'));` This throws me an error that says Error: Failed to lookup view. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: For windows, remote share folder can be mounted as a driver (X:\ for example), then you can configure this driver path as the `views` in Express

Comment: If absolute path is used for `views`, `path.join()` is not needed any more.

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome. I've posted this information as an answer, so that people come to this page can easily find the solution.

Comment: Also, please note there is a mistake in `app.set('views', path.join('/mnt/web_views'));`. The `path.join()` should not be used, it's a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `app.set('views', ...)` to configure views folder, if the destination folder is in a remote machine, you can mount the folder to a local place, and use that local place as the views folder.

For Linux/Mac, the remote folder can be mounted to `/mnt/web_views` and use the mount path:

```
app.set('views', '/mnt/web_views');
```

For Windows, the remote folder can be mounted to a driver, such as `X:\` and use the driver path as the views:

```
app.set('views', 'X:\');
```